# Integrate Google Calendar in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, hybrid

Hello I want to make a hybrid mobile application that contains calendar notifications. I have included a Google Calendar in the html code.

So far to notify the user(for new events) i have thought of reading from the API of calendar and put all the events in a DB inside the app. Then at some points check if there is a change between the DB events and calendar events.

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to get notified when something changes in the calendar, have a look here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

Note that push notifications will always post the updates to a URL you register, so you must have a server to be able to use this.

Once you get the notification on your server, you can use one of the many "push from web to browser" frameworks (google for them) to get the information to your app.

This question might also be relevant, although you didn't specify what client you are targeting: [Using Firebase to send and receive push notification for an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600330/using-firebase-to-send-and-receive-push-notification-for-an-ios-app/19605888#19605888)

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. So, if i understand correctly the Google Push will notify my server and then my server will further notify the mobile clients? For the client part, I want to deploy the app in Android and iPhone market. Do i have to follow different steps in that case?