# Has iOS Firebase SDK support to background updates to notify users?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I want to use firebase but on of the features to this is when the application is in background I want to be notified (maybe create a notification) when the data is changed. Is it possible? Firebase supports this?

iOS has some limitations on this topic, but, I want to know if Firebase SDK support this feature or how i can implement this?

For Android, I think i can use a service to keep data updated and notify the users.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You'll have to roll your own for that.

See:

- [Best way to implement push notifications with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660876/best-way-to-implement-push-notifications-with-firebase)
- [Does firebase handle push notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078953/does-firebase-handle-push-notifications)
- [Using Firebase to send and receive push notification for an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600330/using-firebase-to-send-and-receive-push-notification-for-an-ios-app)
- [Real-time Push notifications with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456440/real-time-push-notifications-with-firebase)
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-send-a-push-notification-with-Firebase
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/NcsozbcxEP4
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/t1MhR_qhohI